# Can not select items of a bootstrap dropdown using the keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu that is populated with time zone information. The dropdown is correctly populated but when i click on the dropdown and press a key on the keyboard (for example "P") it does not select an appropriate item on the list. The code for the dropdown is bellow.

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" name="timeZone" ng-model="engagement.timeZone" ng-init="engagement.timeZone=timezones[37].code" ng-options="timeZone.code as timeZone.name for timeZone in timezones" required></select>
```

***The output is something like this.***

[image]

What i want is if i press A on the keyboard first item matching the letter should be selected. (not to be confused with a filtering like behaviour)

**UPDATE**

This does not seem to relate to bootstrap at all. I removed all the bootstrap classes and it still is the same. May be something to do with Angular?

Comment: I know two way of doing this, Jquery and Angularjs, which one is more helpful ?

Comment: AngularJs would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

As you know using **Boostrap** `drop-down` components you are not able to select an element by pressing the **Keyboard Letter**. So you can utilize the following code which uses a `directive`;

```
myApp.directive('keypressEvents',

    function ($document, $rootScope) {

    return {

    restrict: 'A',

    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

        console.log('linked');

        $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {

        $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e,  String.fromCharCode(e.which)); 

        var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        var target = e.target;

        var charat = element[0].textContent.charAt(0);

        if(charat === letter){ 

           element.addClass("red");

        }

      });

    }

  }

});
```

Up there, you get to see the directive used, it simply is bounding on the keypressed and in the end set the class for the element found with the very same first letter. Nevertheless, you just need to set the focus on this;

```
<div class="dropup">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   Dropup
   <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li keypress-events><a href="#">action</a></li> 
       <li keypress-events><a href="#">something else here</a></li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the directive has been bounded on the `li elements`.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without manually creating the dropdown? I need to have the select element there with the ng-options binding to the data. And i checked with the bootstrap page with the example dropdown, it works with key presses..

Comment: hmmmm, there is indeed much better ways to do this, but so far, I think this is the code I've been working with.. I hope it helped...